# SQL Server. Delete from Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, and have the following query. Let's call this query A.

```
SELECT a.col, a.fk
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN (
    select b.col
    from Table1 b
    group by b.col
    having count(*) > 1)
b on b.col = a.col
```

I want to delete only the rows returned from query A, specifically rows that match the returned col AND fk

I am thinking of doing the following, but it will only delete rows that match on the col.

```
delete from Table1
where col in (
SELECT a.col
    FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN (
        select b.col
        from Table1 b
        group by b.col
        having count(*) > 1)
    b on b.col = a.col)
)
```

Comment: Is `pk` defined as the primary key of `Table1`? If so matching `pk` is the same as matching `(pk, fk)`.

Comment: No, pk is not the primary key of table1. I will edit the column names so it is not confusing

Comment: Still confused, since `fk` is not used on the filter of the first query. For any value of `col` if it exists multiple times in `Table1`, each value is going to show in the first query, irrespective of `fk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delete from Join` syntax

```
delete t1
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.col, a.fk
            FROM Table1 a
            INNER JOIN (
                        select b.col
                        from Table1 b
                        group by b.col
                        having count(*) > 1)
                         b on b.col = a.col) t2
ON t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.fk=t2.fk
```

Answer (score 1):

you can combine **col** and **fk** fields to be another unique filed to retrieve wanted rows

```
delete from Table1
where cast(col as varchar(50))+'//'+cast(fk as varchar(50)) in (
SELECT cast(a.col as varchar(50))+'//'+cast(a.fk as varchar(50))
    FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN (
        select b.col
        from Table1 b
        group by b.col   
        having count(*) > 1)
    b on b.col = a.col)
)
```

Comment: This solution worked great, but NoDisplayName's solution was more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can express Query A like this:

```
SELECT col, fk
FROM (
    SELECT a.col, a.fk, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.col) AS [count]
    FROM Table1 a
) counted
WHERE [count] > 1
```

Which leads to a nice way to do the DELETE using a CTE:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
    SELECT a.col, a.fk, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.col) AS [count]
    FROM Table1 a
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE [count] > 1
```

This does give the same result as the DELETE statement in your question though.

If you want to delete all but one row with the duplicate col value you can use something like this:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
    SELECT a.col, a.fk
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.col ORDER BY a.fk) AS [occurance]
    FROM Table1 a
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE [occurance] > 1
```

The ORDER BY clause will determine which row is kept.